# Is it possible to be agnostic on the properties' names?

Tags: jsonschema

Let's say I want to have a schema for characters from a superhero comics. I want the schema to validate json objects like this one:

```
{
  "Name": "Roberta",
  "Age": 15,
  "Abilities": {
    "Super_Strength": {
      "Cost": 10,
      "Effect": "+5 to Strength"
    }
  }
}
```

My idea is to do it like that:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "characters_schema.json",
  "title": "Characters",
  "description": "One of the characters for my game",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "Abilities": {
      "description": "what the character can do",
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "required": ["Name", "Age"]
}
```

And use a second schema for abilities:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "abilities_schema.json",
  "title": "Abilities",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Cost": {
      "description": "how much mana the ability costs",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "Effect": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't figure how to merge Abilities in Characters. I could easily tweak the schema so that it validates characters formatted like:

```
{
  "Name": "Roberta",
  "Age": 15,
  "Abilities": [
    {
      "Name": "Super_Strength"
      "Cost": 10,
      "Effect": "+5 to Strength"
    }
  ]
}
```

But as I need the name of the ability to be used as a key I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `additionalProperties` keyword.

> The behavior of this keyword depends on the presence and annotation
> results of "properties" and "patternProperties" within the same schema
> object. Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the
> child values of instance names that do not appear in the annotation
> results of either "properties" or "patternProperties".

https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.10.3.2.3

In laymans terms, if you don't define `properties` or `patternProperties` the schema value of `additionalProperties` is applied to all values in the object at that instance location.

Often `additionalProperties` is only given a `true` or `false` value, but rememeber, booleans are valid schema values.

If you have constraints on the keys for the object, you may wish to use `patternPoperties` followed by `additionalProperties: false`.